Phase array for long waves
Can I make phase array for waves that are much longer than the array? For instance, I am looking at 1m array for waves of up to 100m. is it possible?

Maybe explain what you are trying to achieve.

Sorry, i can't.

If the phase difference across the array is at most 1% of a cycle, how directional can it be? Not to mention the lack of efficiency in coupling such small array elements to a long wave.

Thank you. I sort of thought so, but had to ask.

It's possible, of course; the  point of phased arrays is
their directionality, though: you cannot make a tight directional
beam or narrow directional determination without
directions of cancellation of the signal, and 'much longer than
the array' wavelengths will only be as directional as a dipole
is (direction selection due to the polarization  of electromagnetic waves).
